# LazyVStack scrolling stops animations

Tags: swiftui, vstack, lazyvstack

This code lists 100 rows with refresh icon animations.  When using a `LazyVStack` instead of a `VStack`, after scrolling down to the bottom of this list all the animations stop, including those at the top of the list once you scroll back.  No such issues with a `VStack`.  Any ideas as to why this is happening and is there a workaround?
Using Xcode 12.0.1, iOS 14, Swift 5

```
struct RefreshingList : View {
    @State var isAnimating = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack { // <- change to VStack to have animations not stop
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(i) -> ")
                        self.button()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.isAnimating=true
        }
    }
    
    func button() -> some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.isAnimating ? 360.0 : 0.0))
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.0)
                            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animation happens when a change to a view on screen is observed.  In the `VStack` all of the views are created immediately so SwiftUI is able to observe the change in rotation value for all views.

In the `LazyVStack` case, the views are only created as needed, so the bottom ones aren't on screen when the rotation value changes in `.onAppear`.  When they do appear on screen, it is with the already changed value, so no animation happens.

One way to fix this is to let the buttons own the `.isAnimating` `@State` variable.  Then anytime one is created, it will be animating.

```
struct RefreshingList : View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(i) -> ")
                        AnimatedButton()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimatedButton: View {
    @State var isAnimating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: self.isAnimating ? 360.0 : 0.0))
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2.0)
                            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
        })
        .onAppear {
            isAnimating = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct RefreshingListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) {
                    LabelView(id: $0)
                        .id($0)
                }
            }
            .animation(
                Animation
                    .linear(
                        duration: 2)
                    .repeatForever(
                        autoreverses: false))

        }
    }
}

struct LabelView: View {
    @State var
        animate = false
    var id: Int
    var body: some View {
        Label(
            title: {
                Text("<- \(id)")
            }, icon: {
                Image(
                    systemName:
                        "arrow.2.circlepath")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .rotationEffect(
                        Angle(
                            degrees:
                                animate ?
                                360 : 0))
            }
        )
        .onAppear {
            animate
                .toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of works but there's a different side effect now.  When I scroll down to the bottom the animations continue fine.  But when I scroll back up to the top, the animations go in reverse rotational direction (CCW vs CW).  And if I scroll back down again, the animation reverses once again.  The animations don't stop, but reverse direction.