# How to disable position animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, vstack

I want to scroll a `VStack` programmatically and some of child views can be animated independently, but when changing the `VStack`'s offset the animated child view move to its final position witth animation, that's not what I want and how to disable animating this position changes?
Here is my demo code,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var angle:Double = 0
    @State var offset = 0
    var body: some View {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach((0..<100)) { i in
                    if i == 25 {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .animation(.none)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle), anchor: .center)
                            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 3).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
                            .onAppear {
                                angle = 360
                            }
                    } else {
                        Text("number \(i)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .offset(y: CGFloat(offset))
            .animation(.none)
            .onAppear {
                offset = 200
            }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and the effect,
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (tested in Xcode 12.0.1, iOS14):

Use an explicit animation call when setting the `angle`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var angle:Double = 0
    @State var offset = 0
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach((0..<100)) { i in
                if i == 25 {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle), anchor: .center)
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 3).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                                angle = 360
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    Text("number \(i)")
                }
            }
        }
        .offset(y: CGFloat(offset))
        .onAppear {
            offset = 200
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Anticipating your next possible issue, if your animating view scrolls offscreen and then comes back it won't be animating any longer.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64166004/1630618) for what is going on and how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public extension View {
    func animationMovementDisable() -> some View  {
        self
            .transaction { transaction in
                transaction.animation = nil
            }
    }
}
```

based on article: https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/disable-animations-transactions/